# After Market Tire Pressure Monitoring System Question

Tags: sensor, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I have looked into the ways that various types of tire pressure monitoring systems (TPMS) work. It seems that the typical factory installed active monitoring systems use pressure sensors that are mounted on the inside of the tire rims off the end of the valve stem assembly.

After market systems that I've seen so far have screw on caps for the valve stems that are the sensors. I deduce that for these to work they have to depress the post on the one way valve (a.k.a. Schrader Valve) to expose the cap sensor to the air pressure in the tire.

Are these after market type systems considered safe and are they legal in places such as the US?
Since such system is so much easier to deploy than installing special valve stems with sensors inside the tire it would certainly be attractive to the car manufacturers, so are they driven by legal issues?

Comment: My purely speculative guess would be that this would not pass most state inspections.  My reasoning is most state regulations are written to the standard at the time the rule is passed. This means that most regulations state the TPMS light must be off. The light being lit, and an aftermarket system  installed still leaves the light lit and a failure.

Comment: @mikes - If the vehicle in question didn't come with a TPMS to begin with, there'd be no dash light. I think that's what the OP is getting at here, adding a TPMS system to a vehicle without one.

Comment: I agree if the system was not available when the vehicle manufactured. The OP questioned their legality in the US.

Comment: I actually am wondering about this in relation to a old 1998 vehicle that has the passive type of tire monitoring system that always shows the tire fault light on the dash. It seems that the wheel speed sensor on one or more wheels has failed and it could be more expensive to repair than to add on one of these after market products. I suppose it would be another question here to query about replacing wheel speed sensors.

Comment: A 1998 *what*? You really should ask the other question. Wheel sensors really shouldn't be too expensive. If one of them is out, I'd venture to assume the ABS isn't working either (or has a dash light on for it)?

Comment: The US vehicle market madeTPMS mandatory since 2008. Other countries have their regulations whether to have mandatory TPMS or not. The best TPMS displays tire pressure on the low pressure tire. Other factory TPMS may display only the tire when pressure drops to a specific pressure. Aftermarket sensors screwed onto the tire valve may have safety uses; tire balancing, leaky mechanical connection resulting in a flat. Determining a  tire puncture occurred by visual inspection and/or removing the sensor then pressurizing with a portable pump. Some things to consider.

Comment: The vehicle is a 1998 Toyota Sienna with 242K miles on it. The ABS does actually work well. We just had a snow storm here just before Xmas and icy road driving did confirm the ABS when doing some hard braking in slippery situation.